# Having trouble here in LocalPlayerActivity chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

```
 Exception Details java.lang.IllegalStateException: No VideoCastManager instance was found, did you forget to initialize it?   
    at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager.getInstance(VideoCastManager.java:264)   
    at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.widgets.MiniController.<init>(MiniController.java:111)   
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
```

i am getting this in the layout.. any idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an Application to your app, initialize VideoCastManager in the onCreate() of your Application and remember to add the application name to your manifest; all of these are outlined in the documentation.

Comment: I have already declared VideoCastControllerActivity in manifest but the main problem is: 

 1. I open LocalPlayerActivity
 2. I play video in videoview
 3. Then i connect to cast device
 4. connection is established
 5. In this case VideoCastControllerActivity does not open up.
It goes inside onApplicationConnected block as well but it nothing happens.. :( 

But if i 1st connect to the cast device in the activity that is step ahead of this LocalPlayerActivity and then i come to localPlayerActivity and if i play it shows up the VideoCastControllerActivity and everything works fine in this case.